# Notepad++ doesn't ask me the XLM Schema when I click on validate now

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I created a file.xml and a file.xsd. I installed the XML tools in notepad++. After I opened only the file.xml and I clicked on Plugin->XML Tools->Validate now. The following window appears:

[image]

It's quite weird because I didn't specified the XML schema (file.xsd). If I change the name of an element, the xml tools still says no error detected, but actually there is an error.

How can I reference the file.xml to the file.xsd?

---

EDIT The contect of the file.xml is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<note
xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.w3schools.com/xml note.xsd">
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

---

EDIT2: file.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="https://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com"
elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:element name="note">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="to" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="from" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="heading" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="body" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ does not throw an error because a) your XML document contains a reference to an XML Schema file and b) the XML document is valid against that schema.

This references a schema file:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.w3schools.com/xml note.xsd"
```

Notepad++ will assume that there is a local file `note.xsd` in the same folder as the XML document itself.

---

> How can I reference the file.xml to the file.xsd?

If your XML document defines a namespace, then `xsi:schemaLocation` should include this namespace. Your XML document is in the namespace `https://www.w3schools.com`. Reference the XML Schema as follows:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.w3schools.com note.xsd"
```

Comment: Hello @MathiasMüller thank you very much for your answer. If I remove the xsi:schemaLocation, notepad asks me the location of the file.xsd, but, after I choose the file.xsd, the message "invalid schema or missing namespace" appears. Could you tell me hot to fix it please? I posted the content of the file.xsd in the edit2 section

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi My previous answer was nonsense (sorry, getting a bit rusty with XSD!). Now edited, hope this solves your problem.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi "notepad asks me the location of the file.xsd, but, after I choose the file.xsd, the message "invalid schema or missing namespace" appears. " - are you sure that your XML and XSD files are exactly the ones you show here?

Comment: Hi @ MathiasMüller yes, the file.xml and the file.xsd are those reported in the two edits. I'm learning XML from w3schools and there there is the above example.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Those files should work in principle, but you could try `xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.w3schools.com note.xsd"` (without `/xml`).

Comment: @ MathiasMüller my goal is to validate the xml through an xsd locally (it's only to learn a new thing and to understand the code; I am a newbie). Btw you're right, the xsd is at (if I want to take it from the web) https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xsd

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi No problem! I should maybe be more clear: my first answer was nonsense, nothing is retrieved from the internet. The `https://www.w3schools.com/xml` in `xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.w3schools.com/xml note.xsd"` indicates a _namespace_. But your actual namespace is `https://www.w3schools.com`.

Comment: maybe I found an error on w3schools. Here w3schools.com/xml/schema_howto.asp I have xsi:schemaLocation="w3schools.com/xml note.xsd"> instead here w3schools.com/xml/schema_schema.asp I have xsi:schemaLocation="w3schools.com note.xsd"> without /xml

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Yes, exactly. W3schools is wrong about the namespace in `xsi:schemaLocation`, but the validation should still be successful (it is, in your case).

Comment: Maybe have I to add /xml in the two rows of the xsd file where there is http://www.w3schools.com ?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi No, all namespace URIs and declarations are fine. The XML document you have at the moment correctly references a local XSD, and the validation is successful. I do not know why instead selecting the XSD in the Notepad++ GUI gives you "invalid schema or missing namespace". Maybe you need help from someone who knows this Notepad++ plugin.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I'm trying to understand why there is this problem.

Comment: another strange thing is that, if I change the name of the element note (from note to no for instance), the message "no error detected" appears, but actually there is an error because in the xsd there isn't the definition of the element "no" (there is the definition of the element "note")

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi That is very strange indeed. Either there is a problem with this plugin or perhaps you are using it incorrectly at the moment.